# ZeroDivisionError in Ruby Program

Tags: ruby

I am trying to teach myself Ruby using "Computer Science Programming Basics in Ruby" and other sources.  I am stuck on a question and this book does not provide solutions.

The exercise is to write a program that given two points on a 2d graph outputs a message describing the line (horizontal or vertical) or it's slope (positive or negative).  This is what I have so far.

```
# Get the first point from a user
puts "Please enter Point A's X value."
x_1 = gets.to_i
puts "Please enter Point A's Y value."
y_1 = gets.to_i

# Get the second point from a user
puts "Please enter Point B's X value."
x_2 = gets.to_i
puts "Please enter Point B's Y value."
y_2 = gets.to_i

slope = ((y_1-y_2) / (x_1-x_2))


#Check to see if the line is vertical or horizontal and the slope is +ve or -ve
case 
when (slope == 0) then
puts "The line is horizontal."
when (slope > 0) then
puts "The slope is positive."
when (slope < 0) then
puts "The slope is negative."
when (x_1-x_2 == 0) then
puts "The line is vertical."
end
```

How would I make a value that is divided by zero return `puts "The line is vertical!"` without getting the ZeroDivisionError ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all `to_i` with `to_f`. Then you can test for a vertical line with `slope.abs == Float::INFINITY`.

For completeness, include the test `slope.nan?` as the first test to output `Those are not two distinct points!` This will cover the case when they enter in the same point twice.

Comment: added `when (slope == Float::INFINITY) then` to return `The line is vertical`  When I run the program and put in values for a vertical line, it returns `The slope is negative.`  The `slope.nan?` is working though!

Comment: The test for infinity should be placed before the other tests, since, for example, `(2.0-3.0)/(4.0-4.0) < 0` evaluates to true even though it is for a vertical line. In other words, `-Float::INFINITY < 0`.

Comment: Still returned `The slope is negative`.  You did give me an idea though...`when ((slope == ((y_1-y_2) / 0))) then puts "The line is vertical."`  Seems to do the job.

Comment: OK - the issue must be taking the absolute value on infinity. The test for a vertical line should be `slope.abs == Float::INFINITY`. Thanks for bringing this up - learned something here myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
x == 0 ? puts "The line is vertical!" : y/x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also rescue divide by zero operations in ruby

```
begin
  1/0
rescue ZeroDivisionError => kaboom
  p kaboom
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to follow your equation with a rescue, such as

```
2/0 # this throws an error

2/0 rescue "This line is vertical" # this prints the rescue

2/2 rescue "This line is vertical" # this prints 1
```

Comment: I got this to work like this. `when (x_1-x_2 == 0 rescue "The line is vertical.") then puts "The line is vertical."`  I'm not sure why it works yet, but it does!