# ZeroDivisionError Exception with integer, Nan with float

Tags: ruby, floating-point, division, integer-division

I've experimented a curious behavior with divisions.

```
 some_nbr / 0    # >> ZeroDivisionError with 0 (Integer)
 some_nbr / 0.0  # => NaN with 0.0 (Float)
```

Of course, division by 0 is bad, but I'd like to figure out why doing a division by zero with an `Integer` results in an exception whereas doing the same with a float will just return `Nan`.

Comment: The `NaN` is returned from `some_nbr/0.0` only when `some_nbr` itself is `NaN` or `0`. If `some_nbr` is positive or negative then it returns positive or negative `Infinity`, respectively. One can think of the number system of Floats being larger than that of Integers, not only in representing fractional values, but Infinite and indeterminate (aka `NaN`) values as well. This is why FLoat doesn't throw exceptions when these values are the result of a calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer `0` is exactly zero; there is no error. And since division by zero is mathematically undefined, it makes sense that integer division by `0` raises an error.

On the other hand, float `0.0` is not necessarily representing exactly zero. It might originate from a number whose absolute value is small enough to be rounded to zero. In such case, mathematical division is still defined. It rather does not make sense to suddenly raise an error when the divisor's absolute value is small. However, in such case, a meaningful value cannot be reproduced due to the value being rounded, so the best it can be done to make sense is to return some sort of a pseudo-numeral, such as `NaN`.

Comment: "On the other hand, float 0.0 is not necessarily exactly zero." I have to disagree with you here Sawa. If you type in `0.0` in irb, that is *exactly* 0. Returning `1/0.0` is appropriately `Infinity`, and `0/0.0` is appropriately `NaN` with floating point values. This is fundamentally different than integer arithmetic and rounding is a separate issue.

Comment: I added the word "representing" to it.

Comment: Still disagree. `0.0` represents exactly zero. Rounding is a separate issue.

Comment: @Matt You didn't comprehend my intent correctly. I meant that a non-zero value outside of a program can be mapped to `0.0` within the program, which then cannot be differentiated from `0.0` that was originally zero, (and becomes exactly zero). That is clearly due to rounding. You are only talking about the surface (i.e. the definition). I am talking about the reason behind it, which you did not mention.

Comment: Here is an example where a non-zero number divided by 0 is perfectly well-defined: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere In this system, `Infinity` is well-defined. This has nothing to do with rounding. The IEEE floating point system is similar in this respect, in that it is a self-consistent system that can handle similar division by zero. This is why I say that rounding is a separate issue. What you are talking about is one useful application of this system, but it does not get to the heart of the matter.

Comment: @Matt The model that you linked is not the same as float, nor do I see any similarity. In that model, zero and a non-zero small number are different. In float, if you multiply floats with small absolute values sufficient times, it will become `0.0`. This is because of rounding error. The model you mention is very different from float, it is not even a field. Float is intended to be a good approximation of Real numbers.

Comment: The point of that model is to demonstrate that `Infinity` can be a well-defined value independent of rounding, contrary to your claim "division by zero is mathematically undefined". Perhaps a less abstract example is [the calculation of slope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283597/zerodivisionerror-in-ruby-program) in the x-y plane using the formula `slope = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0)` using Float values. If the line is vertical, then the slope has a value of `Infinity` (or negative infinity). When the two points are the same, then the slop is `NaN`. This is a complete description with no rounding.

Comment: @Matt You seem to be assimilating existence of infinity and division by zero, but they are very different. Making sense out of infinity (or more precisely, a number that is greater than any real number) is not that difficult, as that is done in non-Standard analysis by Robinson in the 1960s. Defining division by zero, on the other hand, is much more bizarre; you lose much of the fundamental properties you had in ordinary arithmetic.

Comment: "you lose much of the fundamental properties you had in ordinary arithmetic." Correct. For instance, if `a>0` then `a/0.0` is `Infinity` but multiplying this by `0.0` does not give you back `a` (it returns `NaN`). Nonetheless it is a self-consistent system, however bizarre you may think it is. A couple more examples in ruby: `Math.exp(-Float::INFINITY)` is `0.0` and `Math.log(0)` is `-Infinity` (try it). These are *exact* results with no notion of rounding.

Answer (score 4):

`NaN` and `Infinity` are "valid" Float values, in the sense that a memory address that holds a float can represent these values. This is part of the more general [IEEE standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Floating_point) that ruby adopts.

In contrast, there are no valid representations for `NaN` or `Infinity` with Integers, therefore throwing an exception is appropriate.

Comment: This is correct, but it is not an explanation. It just says, things are defined this way, so it is. I don't think there is anything logical in this answer. Why can't there be valid representations for NaN or Infinity with Integers while Floats can have them? This answer only says it is because it is defined so. Like an old-school teacher.

Comment: @sawa What would be an adequate explanation?

Comment: @sawa "This is correct, but it is not an explanation." It is an explanation on one level as to why the exception is thrown for Integers (because they have no representation of Infinity or NaN) and not Float (because they can handle these values). One can of course ask why are Float and Integer defined in this way, which is a good question, but can this really fully be answered? I think the best we can do is list applications of this. You have provided one application when it comes to handling rounding error to 0 in a sensible way. I have provided an example with slope calculation.